# maven dependency java.util.function not properly loading for function class

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, symbols

When I build this in maven it compiles successfully.

```
package com.hf.arm;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowthModel;
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FP-growth Example");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
        JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("/Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/sample_fpgrowth.txt");
    }
}
```

I need to add a bit of code and so the new script looks like:

```
package com.hf.arm;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth;
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowthModel;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("FP-growth Example");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("/Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/sample_fpgrowth.txt");
    JavaRDD<List<String>> transactions = data.map(
      new Function<String, List<String>>() {
        public List<String> call(String line) {
          String[] parts = line.split(" ");
          return Arrays.asList(parts);
        }
      }
    );
    FPGrowth fpg = new FPGrowth()
      .setMinSupport(0.2)
      .setNumPartitions(10);
    FPGrowthModel<String> model = fpg.run(transactions);
    for (FPGrowth.FreqItemset<String> itemset: model.freqItemsets().toJavaRDD().collect()) {
      System.out.println("[" + itemset.javaItems() + "], " + itemset.freq());
    }
    double minConfidence = 0.8;
    for (AssociationRules.Rule<String> rule
        : model.generateAssociationRules(minConfidence).toJavaRDD().collect()) {
      System.out.println(
        rule.javaAntecedent() + " => " + rule.javaConsequent() + ", " + rule.confidence());
    }

    }
}
```

But I get this error:
"cannot find symbol symbol:   class Function"
Obviously I'm missing the package java.utils.function and so I import this

```
import java.util.function.Function;
```

And I add the dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.hf.arm</groupId>
  <artifactId>arm</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>arm</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.m-m-m</groupId>
    <artifactId>mmm-util-backport-java.util.function</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.3</version>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

But now I continue to get the error output:

```
Lincolns-MacBook-Pro:arm lincolnsmith$ mvn package
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building arm 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ arm ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ arm ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,11] '.' expected
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,12] ';' expected
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,16] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,17] class, interface, or enum expected
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.241 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-10-14T10:05:13-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/437M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project arm: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,11] '.' expected
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,12] ';' expected
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,16] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] /Users/lincolnsmith/Table_csv/arm/src/main/java/com/hf/arm/App.java:[6,17] class, interface, or enum expected
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I can't find a different maven source for this dependency and I've tried cleaning and emptying my.m2 directory. Is there a different dependency source for java.utils.function that I can use for maven or is something else wrong?

Here is my java version:

```
Lincolns-MacBook-Pro:arm lincolnsmith$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Might be stupid question, but are you compiling against JDK 8? Also in your pom.xml, you are hardly declaring your source and/or target as < 1.8 ? I say this because `Function` is only available since 1.8

Edit: ok I see you are using some sort of back-port.

Comment: Another stupid question - where is import statement for java.util.Function? Maybe it will be simpler to use [IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)?

Comment: @DamienO'Reilly He's using a backport of Function for older JDK. Please post a simple example of your code and of your POM, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the full code

Comment: I've just noticed: use `import java.util.function;` instead of `import mmm-util-backport-java.util.function;`.

Comment: Why are you using a back-port when you are using Java 1.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need backport package as Function belong to Spark API, not to Java 8 API. Try this instead:

```
JavaRDD<List<String>> transactions = data.map(
    new org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function<String, List<String>>() {
        public List<String> call(String line) throws Exception {
            String[] parts = line.split(" ");
            return Arrays.asList(parts);
        }
    }
);
```

Then you can build and run your application with correct classpath:

```
mvn clean compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.hf.App"
```

And it works pretty fine (with expected result in my case):

```
...
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:394)
        ...
```

Comment: Ok so now its compiling but when executing it seems to have a problem with the Function from org.apache.spark.api.java

Comment: : Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/api/java/function/Function
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
 at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.j

Comment: and Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)

Comment: this happens because you specify incorrect classpath - not full, specified by maven dependencies tree.